# "I have an allergy to/against something"

Tags: prepositions

as I know from [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/allergy), this is correct:

> I have an allergy to maths.

I wonder if the following sentence is correct, as well.

> I have an allergy against maths.

Can somebody clear this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, though it sounds more natural to say "I have a maths allergy" (British English), or "I have a math allergy" (American English).

@ColleenV also has a good point of suggesting "I am allergic to maths", which probably sounds even more natural and commonplace.

Comment: Do you think "allergic against" is something specific to BrE? It sounds wrong in AmE.

Comment: BrE speaker here - I've never heard anyone say 'allergic against' so I'd dispute that that's correct.  The BrE bit here is saying 'maths' rather than 'math'.

Comment: An allergic person speaking here :) Second expression is not correct. A natural way is to say "I am allergic to maths" as @ColleenV suggested.